# Reply-to e-mail address using CiviMail in 4.6.3 defaults to system default

Tags: civimail

We recently upgraded to 4.6.3, and now the reply-to email address in CiviMail e-mails defaults to the system e-mail, not the From sender e-mail address, as previously. I could not duplicate on the demo site (at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org ), perhaps because the demo site is running 4.6.5.

A real bummer, any help fixing appreciated. Was this a 4.6.3 bug that has now been fixed in 4.6.5?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm noticing this as well.  It doesn't apply to individual emails, but all emails sent from CiviMail are FROM the correct address but show the wrong REPLY TO address.  Haven't dug into the code yet ...

Comment: Eliot, thanks for confirming the bug - are you also on 4.6.3, Drupal?

Comment: yes, same version.  The FROM address is replaced with a VERP if that's selected.

Comment: Eliot, I think I figured it out, partly - in Administer > CiviMail > Mailer Settings choose Yes for "Enable Custom Reply-To - Allow CiviMail users to send mailings with a custom Reply-To header." That then adds a custom Reply To selection in the new or saved draft CiviMail settings. Unfortunately the Yes selection does not seem to get saved in the Mailer Settings. But - some progress.

Comment: Joe  - that setting might overcome the problem, but its not the source.  I upgraded my client to 4.6.4 and the problem seems to be be gone (without touching those settings).

Comment: Eliot, thanks, and can you add the previous comment as an Answer?

Answer (score 4):

This does indeed appear to be a bug in 4.6.3.  Upgrading to 4.6.4 will fix the problem.

Note that additional functionality in CiviMail can affect the from: address: Using VERP or the custom reply-to header.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, wanted to make sure you got the points for the answer